# Visibility Priority With z-index is not resulting as desired

Tags: css

I want to make the link of below snippet clickable. The priority should be,

**link>bottom image>image within link**.
I tried z-index but it is not working.

```css
img{
  border:1px solid #000;
}
.frame{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  z-index:8;
}
.link a{
  z-index: 9;
}
.link img{
  z-index:7;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="link">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="frame">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x175">
  </div>
</div>
```

The first image may stay under the second image which is a semi transparent image. The link should be clickable normally. And it is not possible to alter HTML code.

Comment: [Stacking Context.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pointer-events:none` to the `.frame` class to make link clickable. No need of `z-index` here.

```css
img {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: .8;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="link">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="frame">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x175">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution but  `pointer-events: none;` only support ***IE 11*** and above.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly this will fix your problem, an element needs a position of `absolute` or `relative` for you to be able to use z-index

```css
img{
  border:1px solid #000;
}
.frame{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  z-index:8;
}
.link a{
  position: relative; /** added relative **/
  z-index: 9;
}
.link img{
  position: relative; /** added relative **/
  z-index:7;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="link">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="frame">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x175">
  </div>
</div>
```

for more information you can go here [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)